# Limit of mixed partial

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits

Let $u(x,y)$ be continuous for $0\leq x,y$ and twice continuously differentiable on $\mathbb{R}^2_+$ with $u_x$ and $u_{xx}$ continuous on the $x$-axis. Suppose that for $x$ near $x_0>0$, $yu_y(x,y)\rightarrow 0$ as $y\rightarrow 0^+$, does  $yu_{xy}(x,y)\rightarrow 0$ as $y\rightarrow 0^+$? I can show that $\liminf_{y\rightarrow0^+}yu_{xy}(x,y)=0$ but have not been able to rule out pathological behaviour which prevents the limit from existing. I have also not been able to think of an example even with relaxed conditions for which   $yu_{xy}(x,y)\not\rightarrow 0$ as $y\rightarrow 0^+$.

Comment: What set do you mean by $\Bbb R^2_+$? On what set $u$ is defined? When you write that $u$ is twice continuously differentiable on $\mathbb{R}^2_+$ and mention that $u_x$ and $u_{xx}$ are continuous on the $x$-axis does in means that $u$ is defined at some points outside $\Bbb R^2_+$, where these derivatives are still continuous? When you consider $y\to 0$, is it supposed that $y>0$?

Comment: Thankyou for your questions. Yes I did mean for $y>0$. I would like as few restrictions as possible but additional assumptions which enable answering the question would also be interesting. I just don't seem to be able to rule out some sort of oscillitory behaviour by $u_{xy}$ near the $x$-axis.

Comment: If $u$ is twice continuously differentiable on $\mathbb{R}^2_+$ then $u_{xy}$ it is locally bounded at any point $(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2_+$. So if $(x,0)\in \mathbb{R}^2_+ $ then $\lim_{y\to 0^+} yu_{xy}(x,y)=0$.

Comment: Sorry, I meant $u_{xy}$ is defined and continuous when both $x$ and $y$ are positive. So $u_{xy}$ may fail to be defined on the $x$-axis. So, a function like $u=x^2+x\sqrt{y}$.

Comment: What about a function $u(x,y)=-\int_y^1 \sin \tfrac{x}{t}dt$? We have $u_y(x,y)=\sin \tfrac{x}{y}$, so $yu_y(x,y)\rightarrow 0$ as $y\rightarrow 0^+$. Since $u$ is twice continuously differentiable on $\Bbb R^2_+$, $u_{xy}(x,y)= u_{yx}(x,y)=\tfrac 1y\cdot \cos \tfrac{x}{y}$, so when $x> 0$ then $\lim_{y\to 0+} y u_{xy}(x,y)= \lim_{y\to 0+}\cos \tfrac{x}{y}$ does not exist.

Comment: Thank you. Since $u_x=-\int_y^1 \tfrac1t \cos \tfrac{x}{t}dt$, it is not continuous on the $x$-axis.

Answer (score 1):

$$u(x,y)=y^{x}$$
$$yu_y(x,y)=xy^{x}\rightarrow0,y\rightarrow0^+$$

$$yu_{xy}(x,y)=y^{x}+xy^{x}\log(y)\not\rightarrow0,y\rightarrow0+ $$ when $$x<1$$

Comment: Thank you, but  L'H\^{o}pital's  rule gives
$$\lim_{y\rightarrow0^+} xy^x\log y= \lim_{y\rightarrow0^+}
\frac{x\log y}{y^{-x}}= \lim_{y\rightarrow0^+}
\frac{x/y}{-xy^{-x-1}}= \lim_{y\rightarrow0^+}
-y^{x}=0.$$

Comment: What about when $$x=0$$